# Unable to get correct syntax of python HERE maps reverse geocoding

Tags: python, geocoding, here-api, google-geocoder, reverse-geocoding

I want to use HERE api to reverse geocode lat/lon. I am trying as follows :

```
geohere = here('{}, {}'.format(centroid.GetY(), centroid.GetX()), app_id='WCvPg4vFEghHoPxTaRGM', app_code='yfuHH1jW8oIg7ILD1CER4Q')
```

But Getting `IndexError: list index out of range`.

What is the correct syntax? I am able to use the command line api but wanted to use the python one.

Here is the documentation: https://geocoder.readthedocs.io/providers/HERE.html

Comment: can you post the full traceback?

Comment: @wpercy That's the full trace. I think the way I pass coordinates is wrong so wanted to check the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to reverse geocode, you should add the parameter `method` with value `'reverse'` like so:

```py
geohere = here('{}, {}'.format(centroid.GetY(), 
                centroid.GetX()), 
                app_id='<app_id>', 
                app_code='<app_code>', 
                method='reverse')`
```